# Ubuntu 15, unable to setup routing, getting request timed out

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router

I recently bought a barebone pc and I'm trying to set it up as my home router/server. I've been trying few tutorials but without success and now I'm giving up..

I suppose the reason might be in my network design, but I'm not sure..
Please help or give me some clues.. How to configure eth0 gateway?

Generally, my network design looks like this.

ISP router:

192.168.0.1 is the local address of ISP

myRouter: //(which I'm trying to set up)

```
root@gdn:~# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="15.04 (Vivid Vervet)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 15.04"
VERSION_ID="15.04"

root@gdn:~# cat /etc/networks 
#link-local 169.254.0.0
LAN     192.192.1.0
WLAN    192.192.2.0
OUT     192.168.0.0
```

**Config is as follows:**

forwarding enabled:

```
root@gdn:~# sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding

net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
root@gdn:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug wlan0

#"WAN"
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.31
    gateway 192.168.0.1

#LAN
auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.192.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    network 192.192.1.0
    broadcast 192.192.1.31
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    #dns-nameservers 192.192.1.1

#wireless

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    pre-down pkill hostapd
    address 192.192.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    network 192.192.2.0
    broadcast 192.192.2.31
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    #dns-nameservers 192.192.2.1
    sleep 1
    post-up hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf &
```

dhcpd.conf

```
ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name "home.network";

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;

log-facility local7;

subnet 192.192.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
  range 192.192.1.2 192.192.1.30;
  option domain-name-servers gdn.home.network;
  option domain-name "home.network";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.224;
  option routers 192.192.1.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.192.1.31;
}
subnet 192.192.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
    range 192.192.2.2 192.192.2.30;
    option domain-name-servers gdn.home.network;
    option domain-name "home.network";
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.224;
    option routers 192.192.2.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.192.2.31;
}
```

routing:

```
root@gdn:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.192.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth1
192.192.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

iptables (transparent)

```
root@gdn:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Tests:
I've been able to ping between eth1 and wlan0 subnets, but I'm unable to ping internet/192.168.0.1
I do can ping all interfaces on my router (eth0, eth1, wlan0).

```
Pinging 192.192.1.1 from 192.192.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.192.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Pinging 192.192.2.1 from 192.192.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.192.2.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Pinging 192.168.0.2 from 192.192.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.2: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

but:

```
Pinging 192.168.0.1 from 192.192.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

and

```
Pinging google.com [216.58.209.46] from 192.192.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

Internet works just fine from router:

```
root@gdn:~# ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.86 ms
root@gdn:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ldn02s06-in-f14.1e100.net (213.38.109.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=9.66 ms
```

How to configure eth0 gateway?
Thank you in advance for any hints...

Comment: What's a traceroute from a client results in? You must see if the request from the client reach your router, if it does than the problem is your routing table, if it doesn't than it's your client.

Comment: hi, results from 192.192.1.2:  `tracert -d -4 192.168.0.1

Tracing route to 192.168.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     *        *        2 ms  192.192.1.1
 2     *        *        *     Request timed out  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *`

Answer (score 0):

One may explain it futher, I'm not an network expert, I was assuming, that I don't need to set up any nat within C class, but... hold on, if I route 192.192* to 192.168* then the packet is not recognized by 192.168.0.0/27 network!

Just added :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

That's all. Below the link with explanation.

http://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial

Comment: You need to nat because your ISP router doesn't know how to route packets to 192.168.1.0 or 182.168.2.0. If you can add routes to your ISP router, you could remove nat.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I can setup only one network on ISP router and it doesn't allow me to set routes.